# Help identifying minifigure torsos

Tags: minifigure-identification

Was unable to identify these in Bricklink and goatleg.
Can anyone identify any of these?

Note that heads, arms, legs could mismatch. They all have the Lego logo on the neck stud.

[image: Minifigs]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The leftmost one is [Black Widow - Black Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=109211#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from [6869 Quinjet Aerial Battle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6869-1):

[image]

The second has a pair of generic grey legs and the torso of [Snake Oiler](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sr002#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D):

[image]

The middle one has the legs of [Blackbeard](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=poc007#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from the Pirates of the Caribbean:

[image]

And the torso of [Hector Barbossa](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=101244#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D):

[image]

The fourth one is [Dengar](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw0149#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from Star Wars with different hands:

[image]

The rightmost one has the torso of the [Porsche 911 Turbo 3.0 Driver](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sc078#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D):

[image]

Comment: Was just about to post this, Marvel characters are pretty iconic in their look. Middle one I believe is from Walking Dead, and I think its safe to say that they are all figures based on movie/TV IPs.

Comment: Last minifigure is not related to HP, but has Porsche logo instead.

Comment: @Thanks Alex, I have realized the difference between the Porsche and Hogwarts crests too late :D

Comment: wow! Thank you so much!